# Sensitivity analysis in LP solvers from MATLAB

Tags: matlab, linear-programming, cplex

As far as I understand, [CPLEX](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cosinfoc/v12r2/index.jsp?topic=/ilog.odms.cplex.help/Content/Optimization/Documentation/CPLEX/_pubskel/CPLEX1133.html), [LP_solve](http://lpsolve.sourceforge.net/5.5/) and [GLPK](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/GLPK/Solution_information), among other LP solvers, offer sensitivity analysis.

I have the above three solvers installed on my machine, along with these two MATLAB wrappers:

1. [CPLEX for MATLAB API](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cosinfoc/v12r2/index.jsp?topic=/ilog.odms.cplex.help/Content/Optimization/Documentation/CPLEX/_pubskel/CPLEX1133.html) (for CPLEX)
2. [YALMIP](http://www.google.com/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=YALMIP) (a general MATLAB wrapper for several solvers)

I looked in the documentation of these two wrappers but could not find a way of running sensitivity analysis from them. Do they support it? If not, are there any LP solvers that offer MATLAB support for their sensitivity analysis?

### What do I mean by sensitivity analysis?

I mean sensitivity analysis with respect to the cost function and constraints. Conceptually speaking, sensitivity analysis tries to address the following question:

> How would the solution change if some aspect of the problem is
>   changed?

For example:

> What is the range of values the coefficient for the variable `j` can
>   take without affecting the optimality of the solution?

More specifically, [here](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cosinfoc/v12r2/index.jsp?topic=/ilog.odms.cplex.help/Content/Optimization/Documentation/CPLEX/_pubskel/CPLEX1098.html) is a list of the Java, C++ and C APIs that **CPLEX** provides for sensitivity analysis.

[Here](http://lpsolve.sourceforge.net/5.5/sensitivity.htm) is information about the sensitivity analysis provided by **LP_solve**. You can find the help text for the previous link within **LP_solve**'s main reference guide by searching for "sensitivity" [here](http://lpsolve.sourceforge.net/5.5/).

Comment: Could you explain what you mean by sensitivity analysis? Often sensitivity analysis is done by examining the dual variables associated with the constraints. All of these solvers have methods for  returning the dual variables or lagrange multipliers. Are you looking for some sort of software that explicitly does sensitivity analysis?

Comment: Thanks @codehippo. I just updated the question. I will also be curious to know if there is a way to do sensitivity analysis of the sort I described in my question from the duals.